# while loop applying custom function to mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop

I have a question regarding applying a custom function to mysql_fetch_assoc while it is in the while loop. See code below.

```
//current php page
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ... "); //returns multiple rows

while($rs = whileF($query)) {

    //do some fantastic stuff

}

//... functions.php page

function whileF($value = array()) {
    $var = mysql_fetch_assoc($value);

    foreach($var AS $k => $v) {
        $var[$k] = stripslashes($v);
    }

    return $var;
}
```

My question is I'd like to be able to automatically strip the slashes our of the different fields with this type of a function (and I'd also like to record some debug data if necessary), but it doesn't seem to cooperate too well. If I do a..

```
print_r($var);
```

it will return all the values in an array, but by doing the foreach statement I keep getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../includes/functions.php" and if I try this...

```
$var = array_map('stripslashes',$var);
```

I get "Warning: array_map() [function.array-map]: Argument #2 should be an array in /home/.../includes/functions.php"

The odd part is, it seems like it applies the foreach/array_map functions properly (the values are being stripped). I don't want to turn off errors, just to make them go away as that would be......less effective programming. I know that the whileF() function works properly cause it's still displaying all the info and if I take away the foreach/array_map statements it'll run without any errors.

Thoughts? I know I'm missing something......

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the last call to mysql_fetch_assoc returns false. You should wrap the foreach in an if:

```
function whileF($value = array()) {
    $var = mysql_fetch_assoc($value);
    if ($var) {
       foreach($var AS $k => $v) {
            $var[$k] = stripslashes($v);
       }
    }
    return $var;
}
```

Comment: You have made it on my hero for the day list. For those who care, you can also switch in the array_map() function for the foreach and it'll work like a gem.

Answer (score 1):

Although Draevor answered it, there are some questions I'd like to raise.

1. There is absolutely no point in using `stripslashes()` on the data you got from the database.
2. Though there can be a reason to apply another function anyway. But I wouldn't create a custom function for this but rather create a function to get the date right into array,

and then loop over this array to apply whatever modifications required:

```
$data = $db->getArr("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10");
forach ($data as $i => $row) {
  $data[$i]['name'] = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
}
```

thus you will have whatever custom function applied without no custom functions.